# Errors in grocery shopping program in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm new to Python here and need help with my program that I'm creating for my programming class. It's a basic grocery shopping list program that asks for the grocery name, quantity, and stores them both in an array. It also asks if they want paper or plastic. In the end, the application should output the list of groceries they want, the quantity, and their choice of paper or plastic bags. However, I'm getting the following error and can't proceed without fixing it:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
line 164, in <module>
    grocery_list()
line 159, in grocery_list 
    total_quantity = calculate_total_groceries(quantity)
line 133, in calculate_total_groceries
    while counter < quantity:
TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'int' and 'list'
```

Below is the code for the program:

```
def get_string(prompt):
    value = ""

    value = input(prompt)
    return value

def valid_real(value):
    try:
        float(value)
        return True
    except:
        return False

def get_real(prompt):
    value = ""

    value = input(prompt)
    while not valid_real(value):
        print(value, "is not a number. Please provide a number.")
        value = input(prompt)
    return float(value)


def get_paper_or_plastic(prompt):
    value = ""

    value = input(prompt)
    if value == "plastic" or value == "Plastic" or value == "paper" or value == "Paper":
    return value
    else:
        print("That is not a valid bag type. Please choose paper or plastic")
        value = input(prompt)

def y_or_n(prompt):
    value = ""

    value = input(prompt)
    while True:
        if value == "Y" or value == "y":
            return False
        elif value == "N" or value == "n":
            return True
        else:
            print("Not a valid input. Please type Y or N")
            value = input(prompt)

def get_groceries(grocery_name, quantity,paper_or_plastic):
    done = False
    counter = 0
    while not done:
        grocery_name[counter] = get_string("What grocery do you need today? ")
        quantity[counter] = get_real("How much of that item do you need today?")
        counter = counter + 1
        done = y_or_n("Do you need anymore groceries (Y/N)?")
    paper_or_plastic = get_paper_or_plastic("Do you want your groceries bagged in paper or plastic bags today?")
    return counter

def calculate_total_groceries(quantity):
    counter = 0
    total_quantity = 0

    while counter < quantity:
        total_quantity = total_quantity + int(quantity[counter])
        counter = counter + 1
    return total_quantity

def grocery_list():
    grocery_name = ["" for x in range (maximum_number_of_groceries)]
    quantity = [0.0 for x in range (maximum_number_of_groceries)]
    total_quantity = 0
    paper_or_plastic = ""
    get_groceries(grocery_name, quantity, paper_or_plastic)
    total_quantity = calculate_total_groceries(quantity)


    print ("Total number of groceries purchased is: ", total_quantity," and you have chosen a bage type of ", paper_or_plastic)

grocery_list()
```

Comment: In `grocery_list` function, when you call `calculate_total_groceries`, the `quantity` you are passing is type `list` so, `while counter < quantity` causes error since you are comparing `int` and `list`.

Comment: I added the error. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
while counter < quantity:
```

That line should be changed to be:

```
while counter < len(quantity):
```

Because you want to compare the counter to the length of the list, not to the list itself.

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
while counter < quantity
```

to

```
while counter < len(quantity)
```